# IBOutletCollection for UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, iboutletcollection

Can someone please tell me what are the steps in InterfaceBuilder to connect a set of UITextView objects to an IBOutletCollection? In my XIB file (say myfile.xib) I have a row of 8 UITextView objects. In my myfile.h file I declare an IBOutletCollection:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UITextView) NSArray *textViews;
```

Now I want to connect the XIB UITextView objects to the IBOutletCollection. I tried to CTRL drag from the first UITextView in the XIB to FileOwner, but that didn't show me any IBOutlets. I tried to CTRL click (right click) on FileOwner and that popped up some little black menu. That showed my textViews outlet collection, so I tried dragging from the little circle by textViews to my UITextView objects in the XIB, but that didn't do anything. I searched google to find some sort of info on this, but I only found statements like "connect your UITextView to the IBOutletCollection in the usual way." I don't know what "the usual way" is. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you were were dragging from the correct "little circle" to your text views, because that works fine for me.

Another way is to do it just like you connect an outlet by opening the assistant editor so you can see both the xib file and the controller's .h or .m file. Starting with no code in the controller, select the text view and control-drag from it to the area under @interface, and it should say, "Insert Outlet or Outlet Collection". When you let go, fill in the name, and then change the "connection" pull-down from "outlet" to "outlet collection". After the first one is done, control-drag from the other text views to that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the class of File's Owner is set to the class you are trying to hook up the outlet collection to. Open the Identity Inspector (Ctrl + Cmd + 3) and type the name of your class in the box. Then try hooking the outlets up again.